# Create a logical expression that has this truth table

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The following table has 3 input value.
I need to make a logical expression that has this truth table.

---

```
X  Y  Z      OUTPUT
0  0  0        0
0  0  1        1
0  1  0        0
0  1  1        0
1  0  0        1
1  0  1        1
1  1  0        0
1  1  1        1
```

---

I attempted combinations like AND with XOR  or XNOR with AND. But I can't seem to find the combination to the logic table to get the output of the table.

Comment: Consider conjunctive normal forms (they always work) and then try to minimize e.g. with Quine-McCluskey algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Consider rows, where output equals to $1$, all we need to do is to write combinations which produce each of these rows and then make union of them
$$
Output = (\neg X\land \neg Y \land Z) \lor (X \land \neg Y \land \neg Z) \lor (X \land \neg Y \land Z) \lor (X\land Y \land Z)
$$